# Authenticate User in Symfony 3 without Database

Tags: php, api, symfony, user-interface, symfony-3.3

I have an application where the login process runs against an external API. The API gives me a JSON back which I store in my User Enitiy.(Call it Member)

The User Class implements ***AdvancedUserInterface***.

And my Login Prozess.

```
    $firewall = 'main';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($member, null, $firewall, $member->getRoles());
    $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
    $this->session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));

    $request = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request();

    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
    $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
```

But that dosen't work. Now i'm read [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/459/how-to-authenticate-login-manually-an-user-in-a-controller-with-or-without-fosuserbundle-on-symfony-3) That this Prozess need users in a Database. My application dosen't have a User DB. Is there a way to Login the User without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom guard authenticator: [How to Create a Custom Authentication System with Guard](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/security/guard_authentication.html). I will quickly go over the main steps here, but check out the link since it explains the steps in much more depth.

First you need to create a user class and a corresponding user provider. It looks like you already have done that. You can also skip the user provider class (or create a fake one) if you don't use it in your authenticator class later.

Next create your Authenticator class (lets say `AppBundle\Security\ExternalApiAuthenticator`). It is just a normal symfony service, extending `Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator`. The comments on that class are pretty good at explaining how to implement it so you should check them out, but one thing that could be helpful: You can already check the credentials using your API inside the `getUser` method and then always return true in `checkCredentials`.

Finally add some config to `app/config/security.yml`:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        # ...

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            logout: ~

            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - AppBundle\Security\ExternalApiAuthenticator
```

Comment: Thanks ! Thats not that what i'm looking for but it helps me to find it:D i only need a Custom providerand Config in the security.yml